# jQTouch datepicker

Tags: jqtouch

I'm developing a time management application using asp.net MVC 3 and jqTouch for iPhone web.

Is there a good date picker or calendar control I can use with MVC jQTouch?

Answer (score 3):

I use the [iPhoneDate library](http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch) and it works really well under jqtouch.